# Ascending node and critical inclination

Tags: inclination

I am learning about Space exploration and I have the following question:

Is the ascending node always the same for the critical inclination, or does it change?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to put "question" in the titles of your questions.

Comment: oh sorry, got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the ascending node always the same for the critical inclination, or does it change?

It changes at a predictable rate.

From Wikipedia's [Molniya orbit; Orbital inclination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molniya_orbit#Orbital_inclination)

> To avoid this expenditure of fuel, the Molniya orbit uses an inclination of 63.4°, for which the factor $4 - 5 \sin^2 i$ is zero, so that there is **no change in the position of perigee over time.**"

> **However, the oblateness of the Earth also perturbs the right ascension of the ascending node $\Omega$, changing the nodal period and causing the ground track to drift over time...**

Comment: Thank you very much !!